# Rabbit MQ Error : unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@USERNAME'

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, erlang, erl

Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@YASHODIP-PC'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

- Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
- CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
- Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

- See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
- Consult server logs on node rabbit@YASHODIP-PC
- If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

## DIAGNOSTICS

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@YASHODIP-PC']

rabbit@YASHODIP-PC:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on YASHODIP-PC
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on YASHODIP-PC
  * suggestion: start the node

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-17388-rabbit@YASHODIP-PC'
 * effective user's home directory: C:\Users\yasho
 * Erlang cookie hash: 96Pe9121Rb1vncp1IqXA6Q==

---

I am not able to view the status of the rabbitMQ service installed on my local machine. Please suggest resolution.

Answer (score 3):

This error seems to occur without fail when you run RabbitMQ as a service on a windows machine.  The error message is long and unhelpful.

The problem is caused by there being a different .erlang.cookie file for the logged in user and the service account user.

When you run a command like

```
rabbitmqctl status
```

You see the error described in the question along with the following diagnostic information:
[image: RabbitMQ diagnostics]

When a connection is made to RabbitMQ the file erlang.cookie is used to secure connections.  In the image above this is C:/Users/admin/.erlang.cookie

When you run RabbitMQ as a service it uses a different user account and erlang.cookie file. In the default configuration you can never connect to RabbitMQ using rabbitmqctl.

You can find out the effective user and erlang.cookie location from the log file which on windows is
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log

```
<0.227.0> 
<0.227.0>  Starting RabbitMQ 3.12.12 on Erlang 25.3.2 [jit]
<0.227.0>  Copyright (c) 2007-2023 Broadcom Inc and/or its subsidiaries
<0.227.0>  Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com
<0.227.0> 
<0.227.0>  node           : rabbit@DESKTOP-4HVGMD9
<0.227.0>  home dir       : c:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile
<0.227.0>  config file(s) : c:/Users/admin/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/advanced.config
<0.227.0>  cookie hash    : gCyJOWzQrf6m9e2/Cpz/Zw==
<0.227.0>  log(s)         : <stdout>
```

Here you can see the home dir for the service user and the erlang.cookie hash - note that this is different to the cookie hash shown in the diagnostics.

If you look at the folder
c:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile
you will find another file called erlang.cookie.

If you copy the erlang.cookie from here to C:\Users<username>\ you can connect to RabbitMQ from the command line using rabbitmqctl.

[image: rabbitmqctl status output]

Comment: This works great but it feels cumbersome to do.

Answer (score 1):

with windows go to start menu and search 'Service' and find 'RabbitMQ' and click on start.

Answer (score 0):

This type of errors could happen if you have too long hostname. It's the reason why it explains :

```
If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools
```

## Solution

edit the rabbit's config file (for RHEL type it's `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`). In the networking section :

```
#IPv4
listeners.tcp.local = 127.0.0.1:5672
#...

## write your ip and not your hostname
listeners.tcp.other_ip = 164.81.0.0:5672
```

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but I stumbled across it looking for reasons. So I will write what I have.
In the file /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf

```
export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@domain.com
```

replaced by

```
export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

With linux, in this case /etc/hostname has changed.

Change to old hostname before install rabbitmq

Or
`systemctl restart rabbitmq-server`
and re-create user and vhost